# Talend SOAP API Unexpected EOF in prolog at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]

Tags: soap, talend

I need to call an SOAP API on Talend.
I have a WSDL link , and credential . Everything work on postman and Soap UI.
But not Talend and i have no clue where to search.

I tried the hello world request in a Basic tSOAP
[image]
I get this error :
`GRAVE: SAAJ0008: Bad Response; Temporary Redirect Exception in component tSOAP_1 (TSoap) com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Bad response: (307Temporary Redirect     at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:191)   at org.talend.soap.SOAPUtil.invokeSOAP(SOAPUtil.java:150)   at local_project.tsoap_0_1.TSoap.tSOAP_1Process(TSoap.java:511)     at local_project.tsoap_0_1.TSoap.runJobInTOS(TSoap.java:909)    at local_project.tsoap_0_1.TSoap.main(TSoap.java:758) Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Bad response: (307Temporary Redirect    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:185)   ... 4 more Caused by: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Bad response: (307Temporary Redirect    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:368)   at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection$PriviledgedPost.run(HttpSOAPConnection.java:214)    ... 6 more`

I tried with an esb consumer ( with Talend ESB and talend )
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG70t.png)

And got this error
`Interceptor`

`for {http:------}CustomerWcfService#{http----}HelloWorld has thrown exception, unwinding now`
`org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Error reading XMLStreamReader: Unexpected EOF in prolog`
`at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]`
`at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:292)`
`at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:70)`
`at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)`
`at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:829)`
`at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1693)`
`at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1570)`
`at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1371)`
`at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)`
`at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:671)`
`at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:63)`
`at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)`
`at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:530)`
`at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:441)`
`at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:356)`
`at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:314)`
`at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:334)`
`at local_project.tsoap_0_1.TSoap$GenericConsumer.invoke(TSoap.java:679)`
`at local_project.tsoap_0_1.TSoap.tFixedFlowInput_4Process(TSoap.java:2148)`
`at local_project.tsoap_0_1.TSoap.runJobInTOS(TSoap.java:3138)`
`at local_project.tsoap_0_1.TSoap.main(TSoap.java:2987)`
`Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog`
`at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]`
`at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedEOF(StreamScanner.java:685)`
`at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleEOF(BasicStreamReader.java:2141)`
`at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2047)`
`at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1131)`
`at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextTag(BasicStreamReader.java:1154)`
`at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:173)`
`` ... 19 more` ``